# Can I use a mote from Crown of Stars to attack and also cast Eldritch Blast on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, actions

The PHB delineates the circumstances under which 2 spells could be cast in a turn.

My 15th-level Warlock knows Crown of Stars. The spell says it costs a bonus action to attack with a mote, which to my understanding leaves a full action to attack with the Eldritch Blast cantrip.

Is this right? It seems to check out, but it seems particularly devastating, especially if the target is hexed.  This happened in an encounter recently and my Celestial warlock did monstrous amounts of damage.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] when you get a chance. This is pretty good for a first question. Regarding formatting you're not too bad either. Though if you try to break up big blocks of text and use bold to highlight the actual question it can make it a little easier to read. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## You can attack with Crown of Stars and cast a spell with your action

Crown of Stars takes an action to cast, once cast it grant a bonus action ranged spell attack. This attack does not count as casting a spell so there is no limitation on what you can use your action for. The relevant part of Crown of Stars is below (emphasis mine):

> Seven star-like motes of light appear and orbit your head until the spell ends. **You can use a bonus action** to send one of the motes streaking toward one creature or object within 120 feet of you. When you do so, **make a ranged spell attack.** On a hit, the target takes 4d12 radiant damage.

The restriction you are concerned about is the bonus action spell casting rules:

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. **You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.**

Making a ranged spell attack (which Crown of Stars requires) does not count as casting a spell. Therefore this rule does not come into play. Even if it did you would still be allowed to cast Eldritch Blast as it is a *'cantrip with a casting time of 1 action'*.